# How to write formatted string directly into file descriptor

Tags: c, string, sockets, file-io, file-descriptor

Let's say I have a string that need to be formatted, and then I will write the formatted string into a **SOCKET** FD. The code looks something like this:

```
ssize_t writen(int fd, void *usrbuf, size_t n, bool blocking=false){
    ssize_t nleft = n;
    ssize_t nwritten;
    char *bufp = (char*)usrbuf;

    while (nleft > 0){
        //printf("writen\n");
        if ((nwritten = write(fd, bufp, nleft)) <= 0){
            if (errno == EINTR)  /* interrupted by sig handler return */
                nwritten = 0;    /* and call write() again */
            else if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno==EAGAIN)
            {
                if (blocking) {mynanosleep(1000*50); continue;}
                else break;
            }
            else
                return -errno;       /* errorno set by write() */
        }
        nleft -= nwritten;
        bufp += nwritten;
    }
    return n;
}


int status = ...; 
char* msg = ..., *longmsg = ...;
sprintf(buf, "HTTP/1.1 %d %s\r\n", status, msg);
sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "Content-length: %lu\r\n\r\n", strlen(longmsg));
sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "%s", longmsg);
writeCharArrayToFd(fd, buf, strlen(buf), true);
```

This might be a waste because some data is written twice (raw to buffer then buffer to socket FD). Is there a general way to write these strings just once, directly into the socket FD? If a general method doesn't exist, is there any way to do it in this specific example?

**Edit:** does fprintf() work safely with socket (can detect EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK)? If so, then it's *probably*(?) the correct solution.

Comment: Sooo you want `FILE *f = fdopen(fd)` and then `fprintf(f, "HTTP ....)` ?  It's going to be way more expensive than the method you are doing right now and `FILE` uses more buffers that your `snprintf(buf`. And just write straight it to your function anyway, you just only need to implement `atoi` for conversion, __if__ you really care that much for speed. And anyway, you should use `snprintf`.

Comment: Note: `sprintf()` returns a value you could use https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: @KamilCuk wait, is fprintf slower than sprintf to buffer, then write() buffer to socket? Also, can fprintf detect EAGAIN for non-blocking socket?

Comment: @wildplasser I forgot that and missed a super simple improvement here. Thanks!

Comment: `is fprintf slower than sprintf to buffer, then write() buffer to socket?` "Speed" would have to be measured. `FILE` object has internal buffering. So after `fdopen`, then first `fprintf` is copying data to internal buffer, then on `fflush()` internal buffer is written to `fd`. Unless you call `setvbuf()`.

Comment: @KamilCuk the FD are all socket file descriptor, not FILE. Will update it in the question

Comment: As mentioned in both comments, `fdopen` can "link" a `FILE` with `fd`

Comment: You could use [`dprintf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dprintf.3p.html), but I don't know if it does several `write` calls behind the scenes, or copies to a temporary buffer.

Answer (score 1):

In order to write data to a file descriptor, the data needs to reside in your process user-space memory. `write` will then copy that data into the socket's Tx queue within the kernel. Having understood that, the only way to write your data "directly into the fd" would be to call `write` multiple times on smaller pieces of your message.

This is, of course, going to be expensive: every call to `write` is a system call, and system calls take hundreds to thousands of CPU cycles. The only way you can win here is if your `longmsg` is so big that copying it would take longer than a syscall. In such a case you can format the header into a buffer, send that buffer, and then send the `longmsg` directly into the file descriptor without copying it into that temporary buffer:

```
sprintf(buf, "HTTP/1.1 %d %s\r\n", status, msg);
sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "Content-length: %lu\r\n\r\n", strlen(longmsg));
writeCharArrayToFd(fd, buf, strlen(buf), true);
writeCharArrayToFd(fd, longmsg, strlen(longmsg), true);
```

[Alternatively you can use `writev`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/writev), if available, to send multiple discontinuous buffers to the kernel in one call.

If that's the sort of an optimization that makes or breaks it for you, you may rather look for other sources of inefficiencies, like computing `strlen` of the same string multiple times. However, most likely than not, this is a premature optimization case.

Note about `fdopen`: some proposed in the comments to use `fdopen` as a way to write to a file descriptor "directly". However `fdopen` will create a user-space buffer behind the scenes, just like you already did. Thus it won't do much good.

Comment: Thanks! I guess there's not much to improve here. This isn't actually a issue in the code, I'm just curious about how to improve it if possible.